# Field value is lost when form form.is_valid() = False and form reloads

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm manually rendering a ModelChoiceField in my form so that I can insert a custom attribute on each option. When there is any sort of form field error that prevents submission, when the page is reloaded, the user entered/selected data is lost (i.e. field values revert to what they were on the very first page load). I'm wondering how I can prevent the loss of this information when a form error forces the page/form to reload). **Note**: this only impacts fields that are manually rendered in the way shown below.

**forms.py**

```
self.fields['formpricing'].choices = ZERO_BLANK_CHOICE + tuple([(t.id, t) for t in FormPricingMethod.objects.filter(industryname=industry)])
self.fields['formpricing'].queryset = FormPricingMethod.objects.filter(industryname=industry)
```

**views.py**

```
formpricing = userprofile.formpricing 
form = BasisOfPricingForm(request.POST or None, user=user, initial={'formpricing': formpricing})
```

**template**

```
<select name="formpricing" required="" id="id_formpricing">

{% for value, object in form.formpricing.field.choices %}

   <option 
          typenumber="{{object.typenumber}}" 
          value="{{value}}"
          {% if form.formpricing.initial.id == value %}
               selected
          {% endif %}

    >
      {{object.title}}
  </option>

 {% endfor %} 

</select>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. Within the form.is_valid == False section, you have to

a) grab the field value from the form. Try statement is needed in case its the formpricing field that contains the invalid value and is the source of the form validation failure.

```
        try:
            formpricing = form3.cleaned_data['formpricing']
        except:
            pass
```

b) reinitialize the form

```
form = BasisOfPricingForm(request.POST or None, user=user, initial={'formpricing': formpricing})
```

Comment: `initial` shouldn't be necessary. See the [example from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#the-view) and specifically this note: "If the form is submitted using a `POST` request, the view will once again create a form instance and populate it with data from the request: `form = NameForm(request.POST)` This is called “binding data to the form” (it is now a bound form)." Calling `form.is_valid()` and binding the `POST` data to the form instance should behave correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how it works when you manually render a field in the way that I've described. Fields that are rendered as per normal (i.e. {{form.carselection}}) retain the users input on reload of the page due to an error caused by another field. 'manually' rendered fields are not binding data to the form, hence why I've had to manually pull the data from the form and then pass it into the form as context before rerendering it.

Comment: This is a pretty bad pattern altogether. If you're really insistent on manually rendering the fields, you can get the value from `form.field.value`. Reinitialising the whole form means you lose the error messages.

Comment: Hi Daniel, That's a good point. I'll relook at this. Thanks again for your help!